# How to show split time list of 10 minutes interval using html with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I want to show the time interval list with 10 minutes gap.

For example : `6:00` `6:10` `6:20`... and so on till `18:00`

Comment: The highest level of laziness is achieved. Use simple .js script and ng-repeat on the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();

minute = minute - (minute % 10);

while (hour < 24) {
  minute += 10;
  
  if(minute === 60) {
    hour++;
    minute = 0;
  }
  
  console.log(hour + ':' + (minute || '00'))
}
```